# How to accept a **Promise of hiring** (promesse d'embauche)

Tags: job-offer, job-acceptance, france

I received a legal document called **promise of hiring** 2 hours ago. I translated it from French to English on Google Translate, so nevermind the errors.

> Hello Hani,
>
> As a result of our discussion, I am enclosing the promise to hire you
> and the attached collective agreement.
>
> Thank you for confirming your agreement for the hiring **before the end
> of the month** so that we can prepare your arrival.
>
> We are very pleased that you join us in the ****** project!
>
> Please do not hesitate to call me if you have any questions or need
> more information.

---

### Questions

1. Is it ok if I wait until tomorrow to accept the job offer? I don't want to look like I am in a hurry and I want to enjoy it a little.
2. Should I send them a confirmation mail that I received the job offer and that I'll answer them tomorrow?

Comment: Sounds like they are giving you until the end of the month, but I don't have any experience with this kind of document.

Comment: You are reading way too much into this and I cannot understand the reasoning here at all. Why delay your acceptance by a day when you know you'll accept? Why the need to tell them you'll tell them tomorrow? I'm not sure I follow your line of thinking here.

Comment: @Lilienthal Even if you are 99% sure, wait one day just for the 1%. If they can't wait a day, go elsewhere.

Comment: It's unclear what waiting will or will not accomplish. Do you mean you want to seem less desperate and play it cool? They gave you until the end of the month, so if you really want to play it cool and not desperate, you can wait a day before the end of the month.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wait then.

Send a reply after 24 hours to them saying that you accept and would like to join them. In my opinion, ***you could reply back now, there's no need to wait but if you do want to, there's no harm in that***.

Leaving it more than 48 hours may seem like you're not interested though. Reply that you agree and would like to continue moving through the process.

As for saying you'll reply back soon, that's unnecessary and will look like you're stalling. If you are going to wait then wait and don't send anything until you reply with an actual yes or no answer.

Comment: So @Daniel It's not wrong If I reply now right? i wont look like hey pls hire me

Comment: Well in your question you said `I received a legal document called promise of hiring 2 hours ago` so you can if you like. It's not like you've replied instantly. If I was the hiring manager, two hours later would not raise any flags or concerns.

Comment: Before you send back the acceptance, just re-read the agreement carefully and make sure there isn't anything you want to negotiate further. Once you accept it is bad form to reopen negotiations.

Comment: ok @HLGEM you are right yes

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but in France this "promesse d'embauche" has a legally binding value. They can't go back on it, even if you wait 3 weeks to answer (although it wouldnt be the best way for you to ensure that you arrive in a friendly team). In theory it also mentions employment dates and salary, which they can't change either unless it is for something better and you agree with it. That being said, waiting 2-3 days in my opinion would not be seen as weird anyway.

Comment: It also means that if you accept it and sign it, you have to accept that job and sign the "real" contract unless they change the conditions.